# Unable to push image to docker hub

Tags: docker, fedora, fedora-23

I have built a docker image and have committed the changes, and am attempting to push the image to my public docker hub account.

When attempting to push the image to the docker hub registry it seems to try utilise my hub username as a private server address.

What i have done done so far is run a fedora base image, make my changes and then commit the changed using `docker commit dd09de55abc9 username/fedora-23-httpd`

When i do this and check the image using `docker images` i get the output:

```
# docker images
REPOSITORY                              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
/username/fedora-23-httpd             latest              0b9b4d0b820e        21 seconds ago      468.5 MB
```

Then when running `docker push username/fedora-23-httpd` i get the message:

```
The push refers to a repository [username/fedora-23-httpd] (len: 1)
unable to ping registry endpoint https://username/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://username/v2/: dial tcp: lookup username: No address associated with hostname
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://username/v1/_ping: dial tcp: lookup username: No address associated with hostname
```

From other tutorials I have read my commands appear to be correct, but the output of the images command shows the repository name with a / at the start.

Can any one see what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: looks like a bug, could you report this issue to docker directly?

Comment: Hey, yeah logged with docker support and turns our its something to do with the version of docker that comes with fedora by default (fedora 23 in my case)

I have removed docker from my system and re-installed using `wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh`

Answer (score 1):

removed default docker version from fedora 23 install - reinstalled using

```
wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```